# Transform an image on round axis in fabric js

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, canvas, fabricjs

I want to transform my object on canvas after reaching above the curve area on mouse moving.
 I want to transform an image on the canvas when it reaches the curve of the polygon as depicted in the example. Currently, it is working with the horizontal line with the co-ordinate of one point.
  The javascript function is as follows:

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
  // var activeObject = e.target;
  var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
  var object_height = object.getHeight();
  var object_width = object.getWidth();
  var object_top = object.getTop();
  var object_left = object.getLeft();
  var object_pos = object.getPointByOrigin();
  var object_transform = object.getTransformMatrix();
      // var object_url = object.getSrc();
      console.log(object_top,object_left,object_transform,object_pos);
      // alert(object_transform);
      if(object_top <= 130){
        // alert('good');
        object.setTransformMatrix([1, 0, 0, 0.7, 0, 0]);
        object.setCoords();
      }
      else{
       object.setTransformMatrix([1,0,0,1,0,0]);
       object.setCoords();
        // alert('bad');
      }

    });
```

The link to the fiddle is below:

https://jsfiddle.net/Binit_Singh/1oqLvgxe/2

Comment: i do not see any solution other than cheking where the mouse is. Or you simplify your shape with a generic equation of half ellipse, and you check mouse coordinates over it, or you check segment by segment your path. Other idea could be  giving top and side of cilinder different color ( even just a little bit different ) and check color of the pixel to decide.